# How to disable account if user login fails continuously in Asp.Net Core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

Currently, I'm using Asp.net core 1.1, EF core & Asp.net core Identity in my system.
I have a configure below in `startup.cs` class for the password policy.

Is there a configure to disable account when a user continuously login fails?

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do it like this

```
options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
```

For more details see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

In your account controller, scroll down to `public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)`

Once there, set `shouldLockout` to `true`

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```